# How to bypass Validation rules when running apex class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, validation-rule, failing-tests

We have a managed package install in our org. When I create an opportunity, at a certain stage, I need to create a record of that managed package. For this we define validation rule for certain stages.

In the test class, when I create an opportunity record and reach a certain stage, it throws a validation error.

The Problem is in the test class we don't know how to create a managed package object record data (it refers to an apex class which is part of a managed package).

In order to bypass the validation rule, I created a checkbox field on the User object. In the validation rule, I always check the value as false.

```
$User.BypassValidation__c=false
```

So If i manually set the BypassValidation__c to true then it bypasses the validation rule.
In order to bypass the validation rule in the test class, I made a boolean variable:

```
public class TriggerDataFactory 
{
    global static Boolean bypassValidation {
        get {
            return bypassValidation;
        }
        set{
        system.debug('calling set');
         User currentUser = [select BypassValidation__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
         currentUser.BypassValidation__c=bypassValidation;
         system.debug('Bypass Apex Value:'+bypassValidation);
        }
    }
}
```

In the test class, I create an Opportunity record and before updating the stage, I am setting the variable value as true so that it allows me to bypass validation rule:

```
 @isTest public class OpportunityTest{
@isTest static void testMethod(){
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name='System Administrator'];
        User usr = TestDataFactory.createUser('Test', 'User', 'test.user@psa.com', p.Id, true); 
        system.runAs(usr){
Opportunity opt=new Opportunity(
Name='Test Opt'
);
insert opt;
Opportunity op=[Select id from Opportunity where Id=:opt.Id];
TriggerDataFactory.bypassValidation=true; //set the value to true so that validtion rule should not enforced.
op.Stage='Stage 2';
update op;
TriggerDataFactory.bypassValidation=false; //Reset to False
}
}
}
```

But when I run the test class, it still enforces the validation rule. When I check the debug log, I found that **Bypass Apex Value:** is null, hence I cannot assign/set the value to true.

Can someone please suggest me what I am missing here?

Comment: DML. You need to update User if you want validation rule to apply your checkbox

Comment: Better yet, what was the validation rule / error message? Maybe it gives enough information that you can setup your data in your test to pass the validation??

Comment: Problem is we dont have managed package access and hence can not create the managed package object record without sufficient information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a user and update `BypassValidation__c` checkbox in the user record.

Also, in the `setter` you have missed to update user record.

```
public class TriggerDataFactory 
{
    global static Boolean bypassValidation {
        get {
            return bypassValidation;
        }
        set{
        system.debug('calling set');
         User currentUser = [select BypassValidation__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
         currentUser.BypassValidation__c = bypassValidation;
         update currentUser; //you have missed this line
         system.debug('Bypass Apex Value:'+bypassValidation);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally run the test script with `System.runAs(user)`.

**Update based on comments**

```
@isTest public class OpportunityTest
{
    @isTest static void testMethod()
    {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name='System Administrator'];
        User usr = PSATestDataFactory.createUser('Test', 'User', 'test.user@psa.com', p.Id, false);
        User currentUser = [SELECT BypassValidation__c from User where Id = :usr.Id];
        currentUser.BypassValidation__c = true;
        update currentUser;  
        system.runAs(currentUser)
        {
            Opportunity opt=new Opportunity(
            Name='Test Opt'
            );
            insert opt;
            Opportunity op=[Select id from Opportunity where Id=:opt.Id];
            op.Stage='Stage 2';
            update op;          
        }

        User currentUser = [SELECT BypassValidation__c from User where Id = :usr.Id];
        currentUser.BypassValidation__c = false;
        update currentUser;  

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to set the Boolean variable?
Because in some methods I am not creating user  and use system.runAs() in test classes

Comment: you have missed to update the user, pls check this updated ans

Comment: Instead of creating user in test class,I am using  TriggerDataFactory.bypassValidation=true; in apex test class that I mentioned in test class but it still throws an error.

Must I create a user and update checkbox value in test class?

Comment: you should always create a specific user to run test scripts. It is not advisable to run the script with system admin

Comment: I create a user but not updating the checkbox value and I'm using system.RunAs() but it throws an error  INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD, BypassValidation: value not of required type: : [BypassValidation__c]

Comment: I have updated the test class code in description.The reason I can not set the checkbox value while creating user is because I want to enforce other validation rule and in other validation I using checkbox value...

Comment: Can you check my code and later you can refactor that

Comment: then you need to put your logic in a proper way when to enforce and when be bypass